# Extract version of dynamically loaded JDBC drivers

Tags: java, jdbc, classloader

I'm trying to extract the minor/major version of different JDBC drivers programatically. These drivers are provided dynamically in jar files and loaded as follows:

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL("theNameOfTheJar") });
Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("theClassNameOfTheDriver", true, loader).newInstance();

System.out.println(driver.getMajorVersion());
System.out.println(driver.getMinorVersion());
```

I've got the problem that if the application itself uses an Oracle 11g driver (which is registered in the DriverManager first), it is not possible to extract the correct driver version of an Oracle 10g afterwards. In this case the above code always shows the 11g driver version instead of the correct 10g version.

I've also tried to deregister all drivers first, with no success:

```
    Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();

    while(drivers.hasMoreElements()) {

        Driver d = drivers.nextElement();

        try {
            DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is there a possibility to extract the correct driver information?

Comment: Can you not remove the 11g driver class from your classpath?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. The application needs the 11g driver and there's also the requirement that the version infos of older drivers have to be extracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've finally found the problem. It's simply a class loader issue.

By default, a class loader first asks its parent if it can load the class. In my case the "default" class loader already had loaded the driver. So the URLClassLoader didn't load it from the jar file. The solution was to set the parent class loader explicitly to null:

```
URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { url },
            null);
```

Big thanks @Evgeniy Dorofeev for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 drivers with different version but with the same class name only one of them will be loaded. You need 2 different class loaders to load both classes.

Comment: Stupid question: The URLClassLoader is a second class loader, isn't it?

Comment: you need one URLCLassLoader with jar 1 and another URLCLassLoader with jar 2

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion: The first oracle driver jar (11g) is a static dependency in the classpath and is not loaded by an URLClassLoader.

Comment: OK, then use Class.forName to load driver 1 and loader.loadClass to load driver 2